# I want to print a doubly linked list from left to right and then right to left but my program is missing 1 element from each side

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Hey guys I want to print a doubly linked list with the output:
[23  34  56  52]
[52  56  34  23]
but my program is missing 52 from the first half and 23 from the second half i.e. my output is coming out as:
[23  34  56]
[52  56  34]
someone please correct my code. Thanks !

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
};

void linkedListTraversal(struct Node* head){
    struct Node* ptr = head;
    printf("[  ");
    while(ptr->next != NULL){
        printf("%d  ",ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("]");
    printf("\n");
    printf("[  ");
    while(ptr->prev != NULL){
        printf("%d  ",ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->prev;
    }
    printf("]");
}

int main(){
    struct Node* head;
    struct Node* second;
    struct Node* third;
    struct Node* fourth;

    head = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second= (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    fourth = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head->data = 23;
    head->prev = NULL;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 34;
    second->prev = head;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 56;
    third->prev = second;
    third->next = fourth;

    fourth->data = 52;
    fourth->prev = third;
    fourth->next = NULL;

    linkedListTraversal(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(ptr->next != NULL){` should be `while (ptr != NULL) {` Just note that `ptr` will be `NULL` after the first loop.

Comment: This is a small enough program that you can step through the linkedListTraversal function one line at a time in the debugger to see what is happening. Assuming you understand what your code is *trying* to do, you can check whether it is actually doing what you think, and if not, why not.

Comment: This is also a case where Rubber Duck Debugging could help. Imagine your list has a certain small number of nodes (like just one or two), and think through `linkedListTraversal` a statement at a time, explaining to your duck what happens at each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is printing forward without running off the end, and then shifting into reverse. Following is a version with some enhancements.

Use `typedef` to save yourself lots of typing (and reading!).
Use `calloc()` to initialise the struct to NULL (including ptrs).
Always test return values from functions; you can run out out memory.
Layout the assignments in main() to make clear what you are doing.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
} Node_t;

void linkedListTraversal( Node_t *head ) {
    printf("[  ");
    Node_t *pLast = head;
    for( Node_t *pn = head; pn; pLast = pn, pn = pn->next )
        printf( "%d  ", pn->data );

    printf("]\n[  ");

    for( pn = pLast; pn; pn = pn->prev )
        printf("%d  ", pn->data );

    printf("]");
}

int main() {
    Node_t *p1 = (Node_t*)calloc( 1, sizeof *p1 ); // use calloc()
    Node_t *p2 = (Node_t*)calloc( 1, sizeof *p2 );
    Node_t *p3 = (Node_t*)calloc( 1, sizeof *p3 );
    Node_t *p4 = (Node_t*)calloc( 1, sizeof *p4 );

    if( p1 == NULL || p2 == NULL || p3 == NULL || p4 == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Calloc failure\n" );
        return -1;
    }

                    p1->data = 23;  p1->next = p2;
    p2->prev = p1;  p2->data = 34;  p2->next = p3;
    p3->prev = p2;  p3->data = 56;  p3->next = p4;
    p4->prev = p3;  p4->data = 52;

    linkedListTraversal( p1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[  23  34  56  52  ]
[  52  56  34  23  ]
```

Answer (score 4):

As some of the comments say this is simple enough that you could probably work it out using a debugger, which for the sake of your ongoing coding education I would recommend you look into (They massively stepped up my game when I was starting out!).

However, to answer your question I think you need to be focusing on the logic behind your while loops.

```
while(ptr->next != NULL){
    printf("%d  ",ptr->data);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

What this is saying is "While my `ptr`'s `next` is not null print its `data`". The problem with this is your final (or first) node, doesn't have a `next` (or `prev`) so it doesn't fit the condition to print out its `data`.

Instead, you want to say "Until my node is null print out its `data`", which would look like

```
while(ptr != NULL){
    printf("%d  ",ptr->data);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

Comment: That change will correctly print the forward direction, but would need to do something else to keep a pointer to the last node to start the reverse iteration.

Comment: its showing the first list but not showing the reversed list